# tkinter labels disappearing after time

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter

I basically need a label to be placed, and then delete itself 2 seconds after.

I have tried lots of things on Overflow, but none of them have worked (for me).

def register_user():

```
username_info = username.get()
password_info = password.get()

file=open(username_info, "w")
file.write(username_info+"\n")
file.write(password_info)
file.close()

username_entry.delete(0, END)
password_entry.delete(0, END)

Label(screen1, text = "Registration Successful", fg = "green", font = ("Calibri", 11)).pack()
```

Can somebody make the line:

Label(screen1, text = "Registration Successful", fg = "green", font = ("Calibri", 11)).pack()

Disappear 2 seconds after appearing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

lbl = tk.Label(root, text = "I will get deleted")

lbl.pack()

root.after(2000, lbl.destroy)
```

You are looking for the `.after` method. Will call `lbl.destroy` after 2000ms (2secs)

EDIT: The `.after` method can be invoked from all tkinter widgets, not just root.

Comment: is it ok if you could try to implement it into the code i supplied? i cant figure out how to put it in my code.. thanks :)

Comment: nevermind, got it. just had to change some of . the variables you put :)